# How to generate thumbnails with Dropzone when using the basic way

Tags: symfony, dropzone.js

I'm creating a Symfony 3 CRM for a property database, and I'm implementing DropZone for property image uploads. I've looked around for the answer to my question, but the solutions just say to use `createThumbnailFromUrl` which is all well and good, but I'm just using Dropzone using the easy method, like so:

```
<div id="dropzone">
    <form action="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('property_images') }}" class="dropzone">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ property_id }}" name="id" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm using `oneup_uploader` to actual upload the files, and then after it does this, I use a renamer class to put the image into a folder using the aforementioned `property_id`:

```
public function name(FileInterface $file)
{
    $propertyId = $_REQUEST['id'];

    return sprintf('%s/%s.%s',
        $propertyId,
        uniqid(),
        $file->getExtension()
    );
}
```

Which generates a random file name under a directory using the property ID.

Since there is no actual initialisation and I'm only using the `dropzone.js` from the site, I don't know how to create and name thumbnails. I need to generate cropped squares for the listings, but I am unsure where to do this - would this need to be done in the PHP as well, after the renaming happens? Or do I need to completely rethink the way I'm implementing Dropzone? Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Now implementing the [stojg/crop](https://packagist.org/packages/stojg/crop) bundle for Symfony to manually create thumbnails `onUpload()`.

Comment: Where and how do you use your renamer class? As your are accessing the global `$_REQUEST` array it does not look like in a controller? 

I would suggest to do this on the server side and combining the thumbnail creation, cropping with the renaming step.  The [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle) can help with these steps.

Comment: I'm using a service called `app.image_renamer` in my `services.yml` file. I configure the `oneup_uploader` in my `config.yml`, which in turn tells it to use dropzone.

Comment: can you add this information to the question please, and also if you already use the [events provided by the bundle to add some custom processing logic](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/custom_logic.md)

Comment: I've actually now implemented the Listener and onUpload class from `oneup_uploader` in order to manually process the thumbnnails, using the `stojg/crop` bundle for Symfony.